# In python how to update a value in CSV file which have more than 5K rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I'm a beginner to python, is there any way I can update the csv file while reading and writing in the same file, or is there any alternate way to do this. All the suggestions are welcomed.

NOTE: I have a CSV file with records 5k and above.

> What I want to do is read the csv file line by line and if the value of `msg_sent` is `False` then update it to `True`
>   [image]
>
> Here is the code snippet which I've tried but it is adding an new line at the end of CSV file instead of updating it,

```
with open('subscribers.csv', 'r+') as subscribers_csv:
reader = csv.DictReader(subscribers_csv)
writer = csv.DictWriter(subscribers_csv,
                        delimiter=",",
                        lineterminator="\n",
                        fieldnames=['user_id', 'name', 'msg_sent'])
    for subscriber in reader:
        if subscriber['msg_sent'] == 'False':
            subscriber_row = {'user_id': subscriber['user_id'],
                              'name': subscriber['name'],
                              'msg_sent': True}
            writer.writerow(subscriber_row)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to read and write the same file at the same time. As you specified the `pandas` tag, I'd recommend reading the whole file (5K rows is not much) using `read_csv`, then update the column and then write it back uring `to_csv`. It's just 3 lines with probably much less headache.

Comment: `pandas` is muchch easier - you dont need to put a `loop` n go row by row - just do this to get your result - `df[df['msg_sent'] == False]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above - use pandas.

If you want to update all rows with `msg_sent==False` to `True` just use `df.loc[~df.msg_sent, 'msg_sent'] = True` or even shorter `df.msg_sent = True` as there are only 2 possibilities True and False.

If you want to only write back rows that were False and set their `msg_sent` value to True use `df = df.loc[~df.msg_sent].assign(msg_sent=True)`

Complete example (for case 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('subscribers.csv')
df = df.loc[~df.msg_sent].assign(msg_sent=True)
df.to_csv('subscribers.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

*any way I can update the csv file while reading and writing in the same file*

CSV files are just text files, so you can use tools for text file processing. Python has [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module, which has [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) context feauting `inplace` option, [pymotw.com](https://pymotw.com/3/fileinput/#in-place-filtering) has example, how to *modify the contents of a file where it is, rather than making a new file.*.